# How to show parent/root category on cms template in magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I have a category structure like i have shown below in the given picture,

[image]

I want to show all of theme parent categories on my home page template with link to them, so how can i achieve this ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can not show the default category you have to add category like following
![enter image description here][1]

Default Category (12)
 All Category (12)
   Mobile (10)
      lava (1)
      samsung (8)
      sony (1)
   Laptop (2)

Here All category is Root category and displayed, select include in navigation to YES.